# How to enabled http1.1 and http2.0 both together in a spring boot REST application in tomcat 9.0.14

Tags: spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x, http2

I have enabled http 2.0 with SSL in a spring boot 2.1.2 REST application with embedded tomcat using  configuration "server.http2.enabled=true" and other SSL configurations in application.properties file. It is working fine. When a http2 client post https request, my server is processing and responding properly (java 9 http client is being used). But when the http client version chanced to 1.1, below exception is seen -

```
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.httpclient
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Engine is closed
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2022)
    at KnHttp2Client.sendGet(KnHttp2Client.java:81)
    at KnHttp2Client.main(KnHttp2Client.java:113)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Engine is closed
```

I have tried to post https request using apache-http-client4.5.7 also still I am getting below Exception

```
Jan 30, 2019 4:45:12 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://localhost:8443: The target server failed to respond
Jan 30, 2019 4:45:12 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://localhost:8443
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8443 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at apacheclient.KnConnPoolClient$1.run(KnConnPoolClient.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)


After setting setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(0, true)) got below exception <br>
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8443 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at apacheclient.KnConnPoolClient$1.run(KnConnPoolClient.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Working client for with http 2.0

```
{HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2) 
            .build();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("https://localhost:8443/....."))
            .GET()
            .build();
CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> resp = httpClient.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandler.asString()); }
```

When the http client version is changed to 1.1 as below it is not working

```
{HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1) 
                .build();}
```

Below client code with Apache client is also not working

```
{
final CloseableHttpClient httpclient = 
HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(pool).build();
final String url = "https://localhost:8443/....";
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {                        
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                    CloseableHttpResponse response =httpclient.execute(httpGet);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));                        
                    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                    response.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

I expect that the server which supports http 2.0 should support http 1.1 also.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in Spring Boot, see [issue #15764](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15764).

Currently, only http/2 is supported when Tomcat is configured, but Jetty and Undertow are supporting both. Until this issue is addressed, you can switch to Jetty or Undertow as a workaround.